# Extending the disc size for Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, storage

When I installed Ubuntu dual boot on my windows machine, I just did a 10 GB partition for installing the dual boot. But later I realized that I need much more than just 10 GB. Is it possible to just extend the disc space without uninstalling and reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Sure, it depends on your hard drive and your partitions. The best for you would be to use `gparted` and post a screenshot of your partitions to see if it's possible

Comment: Please be more clear, do you reefer to extend root partition? could you share `df -h` output and describe which partition do you want to extend?

Comment: There is no "Defragment drive" option showing after I select my windows partition

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you've got a swap partition between windows' and ubuntu's one (something like EFI/boot manager - Windows - Swap - Ubuntu) as it is the trickiest scenario.

- First, boot on Windoze and defrag you hard drive (Start menu > search for "defragment" and do "Defragment drive" after selecting your windows partition).
- Then, resize the Windows partition (search for "disk management" and right-click on your windows partition, select “Shrink Volume” from the menu and free the space you want to add to your ubuntu.
- Next, boot via a live-CD or live-USB (see [Create a bootable USB stick on Windows | Ubuntu tutorials](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0))
- Launch GParted, you should know have this kind of configuration : EFI - Windows - Free space - Swap - Ubuntu
- Right now, all you have to do is swipe the swap space to the left (right click, resize/move and click-n-drag it to the left) and expand the ubuntu's one (right click, resize move, expand via clic and drag).
- Press on apply and agree to the warning.